# Problems with fresh Win 7 install on a Hybrid SSD drive

Tags: windows-7, ssd, windows-installation, ultrabook

I have recently purchased a Samsung Series 5 Ultrabook (Model no: NP530U3C-A0JSE). It came with Windows 8 installed but I am trying to make a fresh install of Windows 7.

I made a mistake in the setup and accidentally deleted all the partitions on the SSD drive. Now when I try to install Windows 7, on the main (non-SSD) partition, the install seems to run fine until it restarts and the goes back to the initial config screen of the installation process. The system is the unable to boot from the hard drive. Not sure if that is to be expected or not.

My question is, what is my move? I assume my trouble is because of the HDD configuration being wrong. Can I configure the HDD manually before or during the Win 7 setup or should I try to go back to Windows 8 and take it from there?

Comment: *he install seems to run fine until it restarts and the goes back to the initial config screen of the installation process* Are you booting from the DVD/USB each time your computer reboots? Try removing the media at the first reboot.

Comment: Have tried this already to no avail. It will not boot from the hdd.

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing I'd check is making sure your boot order has the HD at the top in the BIOS.  That way if you leave the CD or thumbdrive in it will not boot from those first.

Second, make sure when you reboot that you remove the extra media (the boot CD and/or thumbdrives).  If you've set your boot order then this shouldn't matter but it's always good to just narrow the options.

And the final check is to see if you're trying to install from an upgrade disk.  A fresh install can be done from an upgrade disk but it will fail the first time, reboot, and make you go through the whole process again.  It will work the second pass so you can check that as well.

As long as you're following all the prompts for the install, then windows should take care of the rest as far as the configuration and partitioning of the hard drive.  One thing you could do if you really wanted (but I don't think you need to) is boot from a different OS (Hiren's, Ubuntu, etc...) and wipe/clean the HD from there.  That will make sure you have a blank HD.

Comment: HD is at the top of the boot order. I've also tried removing the USB key, it still won't boot from hdd. I've also tried running the setup multiple times even though I am installing Win 7 from a full version (not an upgrade disc) medium.

I have Hiren's on hand, guess I'll give it a try tonight.